# Relationship between qbeta and qbinom

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

The relationship between R's `pbeta` and `pbinom` is well known (e.g., Jonhson et al. 2005, Univariate discrete distributions. Wiley):

```r
pbeta(p,x,n-x)=1-pbinom(x-1,n-1,p)
```

when `x` and `n` are integers

For example, `pbeta(p=0.1,x=5,n=10-5)=0.01958` and `1-pbinom(x=5-1,n=10-1, p=0.1)=0.01958`

I am scratching my head for the equivalence between (the inverse of the beta and of the binomial) of `qbeta(p,x,n)` and `qbinom(p, n, x/n)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is there about qbeta(p,x,n) and qbinom(p, n, x/n)?

Comment: How can you convert one in the other?

Comment: If you can't convert them, would that be an answer?